# VHDL Test Bench working but incorrect results when run on FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado, zynq

I am trying to write a program to detect if a given input is a prime number or not. When I run the test bench I get correct results however when I run it on the FPGA it only recognizes numbers that are divisible 3 or even as not prime. Any number such as 25 which is divisible by 5 will result in isPrime being 1. What could be causing this inconsistent result?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity PrimeNumber is
  Port ( clk: in std_logic;
         rst : in std_logic;
         input: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         isPrime: out std_logic:= '0';
         testOut: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)

     );
end PrimeNumber;

architecture Behavioral of PrimeNumber is
SIGNAL current_state: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
signal next_state: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):= "000";
signal max: integer;
signal temp: integer;
signal x: integer;
signal nextX:integer;
signal localPrime : std_logic:= '0';
signal current : integer;
signal update: std_logic := '0';
begin

nextX <= x +2;
process(current_state,input)
begin
case (current_state) is

when "000" => --Initial State
        update <= '0';
        localPrime <= '0';
        if(input < x"0004")then
            next_state <= "111";

        else
            max <= to_integer(unsigned(input(15 downto 1)));
            current <=to_integer(unsigned(input));
            if(input(0) = '0')then
                next_state <= "110";
             else
                next_state <= "001";
             end if;
        end if;
when "001" =>  -- Computation State

        localPrime <= '0';
        temp <=  current mod x;
        if(x > max) then
            next_state <= "111";
        else
            next_state <= "010";
        end if;
        update <= '1';


when "010" => -- Checking State
        update <= '0';
        localPrime <= '0';
        if(temp = 0) then
            next_state <= "110";
        else
            next_state <= "001";
        end if;


when "110" => 
           localPrime <= '0'; -- Not Prime State
           next_state <= "110";

when "111" => 
            update <= '0';
           localPrime <= '1'; --Prime State
            next_state <= "111";

when others => 
        temp <= 0;
        localPrime <= '0';
        next_state <= "000";
end case;

end process;


Update_Registers: process(clk)
begin

if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
    if ( rst = '1') then
    current_state <= "000";    
    isPrime <= '0';
    x<=3;
else
    if(update = '1') then
        x <= nextX;
    end if;
    current_state <= next_state;
    isPrime <= localPrime;
end if;
end if;

end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add your test bench. Else it will take some extra effort to be able to help you.

Comment: By the way, the issue could be that in synthesis, the `mod`operator only supports powers of 2 as right-hand input value. See ug901 v2016.4, Vivado Design Suite User Guide Synthesis, Chapter 4 VHDL Support, Table 4-10, VHDL Constructs and Support Status, VHDL Operators. I'm not sure this is the issue though.

Comment: You don't use package std_logic_unsigned and it's incompatible with package numeric_std anyway. You *could* use an enumerated type for current_state and next_state. For the port input declared as a std_logic_vector `input < x"0004"` could be `unsigned(input) < 4`. Relational operators for std_logic_vector aren't numerically relational. Without seeing the output of synthesis I think JHBonarius is probably right about the mod operator. You could constrain your integers, synthesis would be faster without all the reduction. Show your testbench and any synthesis warnings. testOut is never assigned.

Answer (score 0):

To quickly check sim/syn mismatch, with the visibility you need outside of HW:  output the mod result to a port, sim, should still "work"... syn, compile your (hopefully, verilog) netlist for TB, point to compiled netlist, sim, check the mod result against RTL/expected results.